# How do I convert "_20161002_1630_" into "2016/10/02 16:30:00" using python?

Tags: python-3.x, pyspark

How do I convert "_20161002_1630_" into "2016/10/02 16:30:00" using python?

input = "_20161002_1630_"

Expected output = 2016/10/02 16:30:00

Comment: Show us what you have tried .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `re` module to help with your task. The following interpreter session shows how:

```
Python 3.6.0 (v3.6.0:41df79263a11, Dec 23 2016, 08:06:12) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> import re
>>> old_date = '_20161002_1630_'
>>> new_date = '{year}/{month}/{day} {hour}:{minute}:00'.format(
        **re.search(r'^[^\d]+(?P<year>\d{4})(?P<month>\d{2})(?P<day>\d{2})'
                    r'[^\d]+(?P<hour>\d{2})(?P<minute>\d{2})[^\d]+$', old_date)
        .groupdict())
>>> print(new_date)
2016/10/02 16:30:00
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#usr/bin/python 
input = "_20161002_1630_"

# removing _ from start and end
string = input[1:-1]

#seprating date and time
date, time = string.split("_")

# formatting date
formatted_date = date[:4] + "/" + date[4:6] + "/" + date[6:]

# adding zeros to make time into hrsminsseconds
time = (time + "00") if len(time) < 5 else time

#formatting time
formatted_time = time[:2] + ":" + time[2:4] + ":" + time[4:]

# rejoining output
output = formatted_date + " " + formatted_time
```